# laravel relation with 3 table using Eloquent?

Tags: laravel-5

i wanna use multiple hasMany and belongsTo that propositions uses two function, onece for return notes and another once for return actions 
how can retrieve data note from Action::with('proposition ')

Model Proposition

```
      public function proposition()
     {
      return $this-
           >belongsTo('App\Proposition','proposition_num_proposition');
     }
```

Model Action

```
       public function action() {

    return $this->hasMany('App\Action','proposition_num_proposition');
      }
```

Model Note

```
     public function notes(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Note','proposition_num_proposition');
    }
```

And tables

### proposition

num_proposition
proposition

### Action

id_action
action
prposition_num_proposition

### Note

id_note
note
proposition_num_proposition

in Controller

```
   $actions = Action::all();
   $propositions = Proposition::with('actions');
    $notes = Note::all();
    $propositions2 = Proposition::with('notes');
```

in view

i wanna retrieve data from proposition where(note.proposition_num_proposition = action.proposition_num_proposition) 
using the laravel elequont

Any help plz ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use it like this

```
$actions = Action::with(['proposition', notes])->get();
```

Or you can look at eager loading in the laravel docs

If you use array as input by with should solve your problem

Comment: i tried but in view this $action->proposition->note->proposition_num_proposition doesn't work

Comment: you can dump the query with dd($actions)

Comment: Call to undefined relationship [notes] in model App/Action

Comment: cus its should be like that : $propositions = Proposition::with('action')   -------------------------------$propositions2 = Proposition::with('notes');